# A palavra "meta"

Tags: gramática

A palavra `meta` usada nos sites como [Stack Overflow em Português Meta](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com) é considerada um adjetivo?

Posso utilizar "Meta Stack Overflow em Português"?

Penso isto devido ao uso das palavras:

metalinguagem, metadados, metamorfose, etc, como foi citado pelo [@bfavaretto](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3936/por-que-stack-overflow-em-portugu%C3%AAs-meta-e-n%C3%A3o-meta-stack-overflow-em-portugu#comment10535_3946)

Answer (score 10):

Em relação à primeira pergunta, a palavra `meta` não é considerada um `adjetivo`, mas pode ser considerada como um `substantivo feminino` ou um `prefixo`.

Sobre a utilização do "Meta Stack Overflow em Português" não existem quaisquer problemas na sua utilização.

---

No caso que tu apresentaste a palavra `meta` é considerada como prefixo isto porque:

1. Exprime a noção de posição posterior (ex.: metacarpo).
2. Exprime a noção de mudança (ex.: metafonia).
3. Exprime a noção de transcendência (ex.: metafísica).
4. Exprime a noção de reflexão sobre si (ex.: metalinguagem).

Mais no [dicionário](http://www.priberam.pt/DLPO/meta-).

---

Para além disso as palavras metadados, metalinguagem, etc.. são palavras formadas através de prefixação, pois existe uma associação de um prefixo antes de uma forma de base.

[Mais sobre a formação de palavras.](http://pt.slideshare.net/mestrefinezas/formao-palavras-27055343)

Comment: Verdade. Embora nada disso nos impeça de usar o prefixo substantivado para nomear nossos meta-sites ;)

Comment: @bfavaretto Obviamente que não impede, eu realmente acabei por não responder à pergunta se poderia-se utilizar meta nos nossos meta-sites o que deu a entender que não se podia utilizar. De qualquer forma obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

> meta-
>   (grego metá, no meio de, entre, com)
>   prefixo
>   1. Exprime a noção de posição posterior (ex.: metacarpo).
>   2. Exprime a noção de mudança (ex.: metafonia).
>   3. Exprime a noção de transcendência (ex.: metafísica).
>   4. Exprime a noção de reflexão sobre si (ex.: metalinguagem).
>   Nota: é seguido de hífen quando o segundo elemento começa por a ou h (ex.: meta-aprendizagem).

[Fonte](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/meta)